# DateTime is saved incorrectly into my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm struggling as why my `DateTime` is saved incorrectly into my database.

I pass it the value `20/12/2015` (as a string) alongside the format (`dd/MM/yyyy`) and parse it into a `DateTime` but it always saves into my SQL Server database as `06/12/2015`

```
public ActionResult SaveSettings(ProjectPlan projectPlan)
{
     projectPlan.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(projectPlan.ShortDateTime, projectPlan.DateFormat, null); //ShortDateTime is 20/12/2015, DateFormat is dd/MM/yyyy
     var plan = this._dc.ProjectPlans.Single(a => a.Id == projectPlan.Id);
     plan = projectPlan;
     this._dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint after you set the `StartDate`. Has it been set correctly there? That could narrow down if it is indeed a database storage issue, or an incorrect deserialization from the string.

Comment: @krillgar, up until the point where I call the SaveChanges(), the datetime is as desired (20/12/2015)

Comment: what is the format of the datetime in your database can you double check that

Comment: Use a SQL Profiler and see what's being sent to the database, it might help you figure out where to look. Also, what is the value in the database *before* your code runs? Is it 6/12/2015 by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erm, didn't you mean updating the `StartDate` property of your entity and then saving it back into the database:

```
public ActionResult SaveSettings(ProjectPlan projectPlan)
{
     var plan = this._dc.ProjectPlans.Single(a => a.Id == projectPlan.Id);
     plan.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(projectPlan.ShortDateTime, projectPlan.DateFormat, null);
     this._dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

On this line you are basically killing every context EF knows about:

```
plan = projectPlan;
```

So if you looked at the actual SQL query generated against your SQL database you would have noticed that exactly 0 rows were updated.

Comment: Why would this matter :( ? I mean, I create an object using EF and it tracks changes, so if I change a property or just change the pbject's reference, does it matter?

Comment: Yeah but basically in your code example you declare the `plan` variable on the first line by fetching it from the database and on the next line you completely replace this reference with the one comping from your action parameter.

Comment: I just tested it, and it's about the reference :(. As soon as I do `plan.Prop = proejctPlan.Prop` and plan.Prop2=projectPlan.Prop2` it works! :s

Comment: So basically you throw away the `plan` instance you got from querying your database (the one that EF knows about) and replace it with the action parameter: `plan = projectPlan;`. Don't forget that EF doesn't know absolutely anything about the `projectPlan` variable, nor how it can track it, unless of course you explicitly tell it to (sorry I don't remember that much of details about EF on how you could attach an existing variable to the current session).

Comment: Yes, now you've worded like that I get it. I could see what I had done wrong, just didn't know why it was wrong! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The textual representation is not stored in the server, neither is it in .NET when you have a `DateTime` object. It is just a large number counting the number of "[ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx)" from a set time.

You will need to format the date when you select the date out back in to a string, the inserting side can't control it (unless the inserting side also stores the formatting string or you don't store it as a date and instead store it as a string)